# Rolling Scheme for Months in Google Spreadsheet (Auto update from currentDate)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

We have a forecast-sheet where we need Apps Script to update the cells in D1:N1.

I can make it as is today but it will only update IF the month in Cell D1 is **October**. Which will not be helpful when it's soon cold November :)

Could i refer to a Array in some way, or how could this be solved? I could also just continue with this but the code will be really **LONG**, not so nice looking, least to say.

[image]

```
function myFunction() {

var date = new Date();
var mt = date.getMonth();
var currentD     

   if  (mt === 0) {
   currentD = "JAN (qty)";
  }if (mt === 1) {
   currentD = "FEB (qty)";
  }if (mt === 2) {
   currentD = "MAR (qty)";
  }if (mt === 3) {
   currentD = "APR (qty)";
  }if (mt === 4) {
   currentD = "MAJ (qty)";
  }if (mt === 5) {
   currentD = "JUNI (qty)";   
  }if (mt === 6) { 
   currentD = "JULY (qty)"; 
  }if (mt === 7) {
   currentD = "AUG (qty)";  
  }if (mt === 8) {
   currentD = "SEP (qty)";  
  }if (mt === 9) {
   currentD = "OKT (qty)";  
  }if (mt === 10){
  currentD = "NOV (qty)";
  }else if (mt === 11){
  currentD = "DEC (qty)";
  }

 Logger.log("CurrentD: " +currentD); 

  var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spr.getSheets()[0];

 //D_MONTH    
 var range = sheet.getRange("D1");
 var cell = range.getCell(1, 1);
 var D_MONTH = cell.getValue();
 Logger.log("D_MONTH: " + D_MONTH);


  if(D_MONTH != currentD) {

     cell.setValue(currentD);
  }


   //E_MONTH    
 var range = sheet.getRange("E1");
 var cell = range.getCell(1, 1);
 var E_MONTH = cell.getValue();



  if(currentD === "OKT (qty)") {

     cell.setValue("NOV (qty)");
  }

  //F_MONTH    
 var range = sheet.getRange("F1");
 var cell = range.getCell(1, 1);
 var F_MONTH = cell.getValue();



  if(currentD === "OKT (qty)") {

     cell.setValue("DEC (qty)");
  }

    //G_MONTH    
 var range = sheet.getRange("G1");
 var cell = range.getCell(1, 1);
 var G_MONTH = cell.getValue();



  if(currentD === "OKT (qty)") {

     cell.setValue("JAN (qty)");
  }

   //H_MONTH    
 var range = sheet.getRange("H1");
 var cell = range.getCell(1, 1);
 var H_MONTH = cell.getValue();



  if(currentD === "OKT (qty)") {

     cell.setValue("FEB (qty)");
  }


    //I_MONTH    
 var range = sheet.getRange("I1");
 var cell = range.getCell(1, 1);
 var I_MONTH = cell.getValue();



  if(currentD === "OKT (qty)") {

     cell.setValue("MAR (qty)");
  }

    //J_MONTH    
 var range = sheet.getRange("J1");
 var cell = range.getCell(1, 1);
 var J_MONTH = cell.getValue();



  if(currentD === "OKT (qty)") {

     cell.setValue("APR (qty)");
  }

    //K_MONTH    
 var range = sheet.getRange("K1");
 var cell = range.getCell(1, 1);
 var K_MONTH = cell.getValue();



  if(currentD === "OKT (qty)") {

     cell.setValue("MAJ (qty)");
  }

     //L_MONTH    
 var range = sheet.getRange("L1");
 var cell = range.getCell(1, 1);
 var L_MONTH = cell.getValue();



  if(currentD === "OKT (qty)") {

     cell.setValue("JUNI (qty)");
  }

      //M_MONTH    
 var range = sheet.getRange("M1");
 var cell = range.getCell(1, 1);
 var M_MONTH = cell.getValue();



  if(currentD === "OKT (qty)") {

     cell.setValue("JULY (qty)");
  }

     //N_MONTH    
 var range = sheet.getRange("N1");
 var cell = range.getCell(1, 1);
 var N_MONTH = cell.getValue();



  if(currentD === "OKT (qty)") {

     cell.setValue("AUG (qty)");
  }






}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't repeat yourself - if your code starts looking like a pattern there's a good chance you can refactor it into something more concise.

This should do what you need. It checks the first column, returns if it's the current month. If not it starts overwriting with the current month name and the following ones to the right wrapping around to the next year.

```
function setDates(){
  var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
                    "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep",
                    "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

  var currentMonths = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("D1:N1").getValues()[0];
  var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();

  if (currentMonths[0] == monthNames[currentMonth]){return;}

  for (var col = 0; col < currentMonths.length; col++){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                  .getActiveSheet()
                  .getRange(1,4+col)
                  .setValue(monthNames[(currentMonth + col > 11 ?
                                        currentMonth + col - 12 :
                                        currentMonth + col)]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Robin, exactly what i was looking for, you really got what i was looking for, spot on! This was what i thought about but couldn't achieve without your help. Works like a charm now, just needed to att the (Qty) to the montNames :)